# Declaring a variable with casper.evaluate

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, evaluate

In the following example I'm trying to declare a global variable named `foo` in the using evaluate. And then outputing it using using the script on the webpage. But an error message indicates the variable has not been defined.

## The webpage : index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charser="utf-8">
  <title> Page title </title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
  window.onload = function() {
    console.log('started webpage script');
    console.log(foo);
  };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Casper script : casper.js

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose : true,
  logLevel : "debug"
});


casper.start('http://localhost:8080');

casper.on('page.error', function(err) {
  this.echo(err, 'ERROR');
});


casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
  this.echo(msg);
});

casper.on('run.start', function() {
  casper.evaluate(function() {
    console.log('Running evaluate script');
    window.foo = "Hello world!";
  });
});


casper.run();
```

## Terminal output

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 2 steps
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
Running evaluate script
[debug] [phantom] opening url: http://localhost:8080/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=http://localhost:8080/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "http://localhost:8080/"
started webpage script
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: foo
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[debug] [phantom] start page is loaded
[info] [phantom] Done 2 steps in 65ms
```

Comment: Have tried changing run.start to starting or started? At run.start there is simply no webpage to inject your js. You may also want to check out the events page.created and page.initialized

Comment: Have you tried declaring the variable on the web page first and assigning it from casper?

Comment: `page.initialized` did it thanks

Comment: @YoussefBouhjira You can share your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to call casper.evaluate() on `page.initialize`

```
casper.on('page.initialize', function() {
  casper.evaluate(function() {
    console.log('Running evaluate script');
    window.foo = "Hello world!";
  });
});
```